# Mongoose limit and total count in mapReduce

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I need to run a query which returns total count of documents together with documents and that can be limited and offset. It's similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13935733/mongoose-limit-offset-and-count-query) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15717367/mongoose-skip-limit-and-count) question. The difference is that I run map/reduce and total count is already available in `stats` argument so hopefully I don't have to call the query twice.

```
list: function (options, cb) {
    ...
    this.mapReduce(o, function (err, model, stats) {
        console.log('# of documents: %d ', stats.counts.output);
        model.find()
            .limit(criteria.perPage)
            .skip(criteria.perPage * criteria.page)
            .exec(cb);
    });
});
```

I call the `list` function from controller like this:

```
Track.list(options, function (err, docs) {
    res.json(docs);
});
```

Is it somehow possible to pass `stats.counts.output` to the controller together with returned documents?

Comment: Thanks for the reference to `stats.counts.output`. I was looking for how to do `.count()` and `.find()` in a single query and at least when using `mapReduce` it seems possible.

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap the `cb` within a function in the argument to `exec`:

```
model.find()
    .limit(criteria.perPage)
    .skip(criteria.perPage * criteria.page)
    .exec(function (err, docs) {
      cb(err, docs, stats.counts.output)
    });

Track.list(options, function (err, docs, count) {
    res.json({docs: docs, count: count})
})
```