# Limiting Query result in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have 20,000+ documents in my mongodb. I just learnt that you cannot query them all in one go.

So my question is this:

I want to get my document using `find(query)` then limit its results for 3 documents only and I can choose where those documents start from.

For example if my `find()` query resulted in 8 documents :

```
[{doc1}, {doc2}, {doc3}, {doc4}, {doc5}, {doc6}, {doc7}, {doc 8}]
```

command `limit(2, 3)` will gives `[doc3, doc4, doc5]`

And I also need to get total count for all that result(without limit) for example : `length()` will give `8` (the number of total document resulted from `find()` function)

Any suggestion? Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suppose you have the following documents in your collection.

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("56801243fb940e32f3221bc2"), "a" : 0 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("56801243fb940e32f3221bc3"), "a" : 1 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("56801243fb940e32f3221bc4"), "a" : 2 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("56801243fb940e32f3221bc5"), "a" : 3 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("56801243fb940e32f3221bc6"), "a" : 4 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("56801243fb940e32f3221bc7"), "a" : 5 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("56801243fb940e32f3221bc8"), "a" : 6 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("56801243fb940e32f3221bc9"), "a" : 7 }
```

From MongoDB 3.2 you can use the [`.aggregate()`](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.2/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/#db.collection.aggregate) method and the [`$slice`](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.2/reference/operator/aggregation/slice/#exp._S_slice) operator.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$group": {
        "_id": null, 
        "count": { "$sum": 1 }, 
        "docs": { "$push": "$$ROOT" }
    }}, 
    { "$project": { 
        "count": 1, 
        "_id": 0,
        "docs": { "$slice": [ "$docs", 2, 3 ] }
    }}
])
```

Which returns:

```
{
        "count" : 8,
        "docs" : [
                {
                        "_id" : ObjectId("56801243fb940e32f3221bc4"),
                        "a" : 2
                },
                {
                        "_id" : ObjectId("56801243fb940e32f3221bc5"),
                        "a" : 3
                },
                {
                        "_id" : ObjectId("56801243fb940e32f3221bc6"),
                        "a" : 4
                }
        ]
}
```

You may want to sort your document before grouping using the [`$sort`](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.2/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/#pipe._S_sort) operator.

---

From MongoDB 3.0 backwards you will need to first [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.2/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group) your documents and use the [`$sum`](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.2/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/#grp._S_sum) accumulator operator to return the "count" of documents; also in that same group stage you need to use the [`$push`](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.2/reference/operator/aggregation/push/#grp._S_push) and the [`$$ROOT`](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/aggregation-variables/#variable.ROOT) variable to return an array of all your documents. The next stage in the pipeline will then be the [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.2/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/#pipe._S_unwind) stage where you denormalize that array. From there use use the [`$skip`](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.2/reference/operator/aggregation/skip/#pipe._S_skip) and [`$limit`](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.2/reference/operator/aggregation/limit/#pipe._S_limit) operators respectively skip the first 2 documents and passes 3 documents to the next stage which is another [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.2/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group) stage.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$group": {
        "_id": null, 
        "count": { "$sum": 1 }, 
        "docs": { "$push": "$$ROOT" }
    }}, 
    { "$unwind": "$docs" }, 
    { "$skip": 2 }, 
    { "$limit": 3 }, 
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$_id", 
        "count": { "$first": "$count" }, 
        "docs": { "$push": "$docs" }
    }}
])
```

---

As @JohnnyHK pointed out in this [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34482145/limiting-query-result-in-mongodb/34482505#comment56707535_34482505)

> `$group` is going to read all documents and build a 20k element array with them just to get three docs.

You should then run two queries using `find()`

```
db.collection.find().skip(2).limit(3)
```

and

```
db.collection.count()
```

Comment: Good ideas, but that `$group` is going to read all documents and build a 20k element array with them just to get three docs. Hard to believe this would be more efficient than two queries.

Answer (score 10):

add `.skip(2).limit(3)` to the end of your query

Comment: Ah, thank you for such quick answer. So how I get the total result ? I mean, I want to know how many document count form find() without querying the same search parameter twice ?

Comment: I am not sure what do you mean. you want to count how many results did you get by limiting result set to 3?

Comment: No, I building a datatable (jquery datatable) and it requires something like -  var total = db.transaction.find().length; and var data = db.transaction.find().skip(2).limit(3). TOTAL and DATA are different thing

Comment: total count is gtiven by .count() at end of find() function

Comment: Yes, your answer is also correct and I even write the same code with count() function. But it's inefficient since I need to query such a big data twice : first to get its total count and second, just to split it.

Comment: well, then you should have stated that in the question in the first place. I think I answered exactly what you asked. answering question about how to skip and limit find query in mongo with description of aggregation pipeline would have been an overkill.

Comment: @MartinsUntals the problem was you not trying to ask clarification and trying to answer a question that was "too broad", easy or  that could be closed as a possible duplicate of [Mongoose limit/offset and count query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13935733/mongoose-limit-offset-and-count-query)

Comment: probably. though how can it be duplicate of anything related to mongoose, if this is pure mongo question? I can agree it being too easy though. Such questions should not be answered without asking extra questions first? - I am not sure, as I do not have extensive experience with writing answers yet.

Comment: @MartinsUntals: My bad, I'm so sorry I forget to add detail about total earlier.  Thank you for your answer though