# How to add Lazy loading in Node js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, lazy-loading

```
const posts = await Post.find().populate("receiver").populate("author")
        try {
            res.json({
                status: true,
                message: 'All posts fetched',
                data: posts.reverse()
            })
```

This is my code that sending all posts to frontend. But I want add lazy loading on backend.
**Backend must not send all the data at one go.. calling 1000 feed posts after sometime interval.
The data will be too large to call via api.**

Comment: Since you are using `populate` I assume you are using mongoose, try adding pagination

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13935733/mongoose-limit-offset-and-count-query) you can see how skip and limit is used in mongoose

Answer (score 1):

First thing i see: Why didnt you put your `await` inside the `try / catch` block?

You can use `skip` and `limit`

I like to do it like this:

```
    let page = req.body.page - 1;
    let postAmount = 10;
    try {
        const posts = await Post.find().populate("receiver").populate("author").limit(postAmount).skip(postAmount * page)
        res.json({
            status: true,
            message: 'All posts fetched',
            data: posts.reverse()
        })
```

Depending on if you use GET or POST you will need to send additional `page` to your API.

On page 1 you will see 10 posts. At skip you have 10 multiply by 1 that is 10 but you dont want to skip 10 posts on your first fetch. So you need to subscract `-1` to have 10 multiply by 0 is 0 so you skip 0 at your first fetch.