# handle big collection in mongo

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a collection of 100,000 in Mongo Collection.
How to display this information to the user in batches of 100 without displaying duplicate information to the user Page by page in node js with mongoose

Comment: What do you mean by duplicate information? Can you please clarify this moment?

Comment: query method `skip` and `limit` maybe helpful

Answer (score 0):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/64376270/10368610

Use pagination concept(skip, limit) with help of the total value of the record