# How to implement Pagination with Ktor and Kmongo

Tags: mongodb, kotlin, pagination, ktor, kmongo

**Problem:**
To Implement Pagination on the server side using Ktor and Kmongo.

**Tech Stacks:**

Kotlin as Programming Language.

Ktor as Web Framework.

MongoDb as database.

Kmongo as Sql framework.

**I cannot find any tutorial or posts that describes to implement pagination with Database in Ktor.**

Comment: Did you implement something and stuck? I don't think there are such specific tutorials.

Comment: I have implemented one but that was not using database.

Comment: Then just use those values to calculate an offset and limit to retrieve only specific documents from MongoDB https://stackoverflow.com/a/15387497/13963150.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I implemented the same.

```
override suspend fun getAllUsers(page: Int, limit: Int): List<User> {
    return database.getCollection<User>().find().skip(skip = (page - 1) * limit).limit(limit = limit)
        .partial(true).descendingSort(User::lastLoginTime).toList()
}
```

Thanks to [@Aleksei Tirman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13963150/aleksei-tirman).

For More see - https://stackoverflow.com/a/15387497/13963150