# How results pagination works with Node.js, Jade, Mongoose and Bootstrap?

Tags: node.js, twitter-bootstrap, express, pagination, pug

Can someone help me with some tips about how to paginate results from a mongoose query? The correct is to send all the results at a time to the browser or get them by some range? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your answer can be found here: [How to paginate with Mongoose in Node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5539955/how-to-paginate-with-mongoose-in-node-js)

Using Skip and Limit:

```
.find({}).sort('mykey', 1).skip(from).limit(to)
```

Mongo Docs: [Skip](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.skip/)  | [Limit](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.limit/)