# Express js pagination in mean.io stack

Tags: angularjs, express, pagination

how to make a server side pagination in mean.io stack application.i.e express should load only 10 documents from 30 document available in mongodb,@ express level on pageload , on click of second page number (1,2,3) in pagination next 10 record should be fetch on click of third page next 10 record should be fetch.

Answer (score 0):

You should start from updating mongoose models (described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5539955/how-to-paginate-with-mongoose-in-node-js)).

Then add appropriate params to controllers.

To add pagination to angularjs use [angular-ui-pagination](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/pagination)

Comment: thanks for the response , i have tried the same thing mentioned in the answer but my real challenge lies in how to link the express function with angular controller

Comment: i.e  i want skip to be dynamic value that will come from url or some thing , please help..

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MEAN stack following blog post provides much of the information to create pagination in front end using angular-UI bootstrap and using mongoose skip and limit methods in the backend. this can also be applicable for MEAN IO.

see : https://techpituwa.wordpress.com/2015/06/06/mean-js-pagination-with-angular-ui-bootstrap/