# How to exclude last record from result in mongoose query

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have a query something like this in mongoose.

```
var query=Videopost.findOne({}, {}, { sort: { '_id' : -1 } });
```

I want to exclude last record inserted in database from result.
Any help will be appreciated!!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to paginate with Mongoose in Node.js?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5539955/how-to-paginate-with-mongoose-in-node-js)

Comment: `findOne` is always going to return only one document. Did you mean `find()`?

Comment: chain `skip(1)` to the query. It would skip the most recently added record.

Comment: @BatScream : i have tried that Videopost.find({}).skip(1).. but it is skipping first record what i have inserted not the last one.

Comment: you need to keep the sort and skip operations chained together- `find({}).sort({"_id":-1}).skip(1)`

Comment: Thanks for your support!! Can you post in the answer @BatScream

Comment: you are most welcome @KishorMishra. I think the question has an answer on the link posted as part of the first comment.so  If i post an answer here, it would be repetitive. Will be glad to post next time around. Happy coding.