# how to set limit,offset,skip in mongoose query

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I am using express,mongoose,node.so i have checked this query regarding to skip and limit of documents.

```
   Model.find({},null,{limit:2,skip:20},function(err,data){
           //console.log(data)
      })
```

Answer (score 13):

not sure but I think it's help full for you.

```
var perPage = 10
  , page = Math.max(0, req.param('page'))

Event.find()
    .select('name')
    .skip(perPage * page)
    .limit(perPage)
    .sort({
        name: 'asc'
    })
    .exec(function(err, events) {
        Event.count().exec(function(err, count) {
            res.render('events', {
                events: events,
                page: page,
                pages: count / perPage
            })
        })
    })
```

or see

[How to paginate with Mongoose in Node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5539955/how-to-paginate-with-mongoose-in-node-js)

Comment: How would you get the results for page 1? Wouldn't that return the results for page 2 instead?

Comment: I think the best way is to `skip((pageNumber - 1) * limit)` which would skip `nothing (or 0) for page 1, limit for page 2, limit + limit for page 3, limit + limit + limit for page 4, limit * (n - 1) for page n`

Comment: Close... But as @ckwagaba said this skips first 10 all the time. Use (page - 1) * skip for the correct algo.

Answer (score 9):

```
var query = Model.find({}).skip(2).limit(5)
query.exec(callback);
```

write your code in `callback`

```
query.exec(function(err,data){
   //console.log(data)
});
```

You can also do some more query like this

```
Model
.where('field1').gte(25)
.where().in([])
.select('field1', 'field2', 'field13')
.skip(20)
.limit(10)
.asc('field1')
.exec(callback);
```

You can refer [docs](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/2.7.x/docs/finding-documents.html) for more details

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
Model.find({},null,{limit:2,skip:20}).then(function(data){
       //console.log(data)
  }).catch(next);
```