# How can I do pagination with mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

All of the other solutions use skip() which is apparently bad for speed. Also I have seen people use nin which seems like it could be a bad solution if you have a bunch of ids that you are checking. Here is what I have so far

```
//Get the top 20 posts initially
  exports.getPosts = (req, res) => {
     db.post.find().sort({
         numberOfLikes: -1
     }).limit(20).exec(function(err, posts){
         if(err){
             return res.status(500).send();
         }

         res.json(posts);
     });
};

//This is to enable pagination on posts
exports.getMorePosts = (req, res) => {
    var query = req.query;

    if(!query.hasOwnProperty('numberOfLikes') || !query.hasOwnProperty('postId')){
        return res.status(400).send();
    }

    db.post.find({
        numberOfLikes: {
            $lte: query.numberOfLikes
        },
        _id: {
            $ne: query.postId
        }
    }).sort('-numberOfLikes').limit(20).exec(function(err, posts){
        if(err){
            return res.status(500).send();
        }

        res.json(posts);
    });
};
```

So I use the first function to get the first 20 posts and then the second to get 20 more posts and so on. The second function get passed the smallest number of likes from the original 20 and the last post's postId from the original 20. From there it gets 20 more.

I want to sort them by the number of likes but the problem is once it gets posts with 0 likes, it never knows when to end and it just keeps cycling back and fourth.

Comment: Possible dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5539955/how-to-paginate-with-mongoose-in-node-js

Comment: Not a duplication. Mine is a more specific case. Thanks though

Comment: The point is that right way to do this is one of the approaches in the dupe. Using `_id: {$ne: query.post}` just excludes the _last_ post from the previous query, not all the post with the same `numberOfLikes` that are on the previous pages. Using a non-skip based approach when what you're sorting on isn't unique doesn't work well. I'd suggest indexing `numberOfLikes` and use `skip` and `limit` and evaluate its performance.