# Pagination: How to know if there are more documents in a mongoDB collection?

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, mongodb, pagination

How can I know if there're more documents in mongo query that implements `limit()`

[Is there a way to know if there are more documents available for pagination in MongoDB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42713235/is-there-a-way-to-know-if-there-are-more-documents-available-for-pagination-in-m). Following the example shared in this post, I somehow still end up getting a `false` flag but I am sure there's a next page

```
  let pagelimit = number || 10
  const items = db.find({}).sort({ _id: 1 }).limit(pagelimit).toArray()
 
  items.length > page limit + 1 // false
  items.length > page limit // false
```

Tried  `items.length > page limit + 1` and `items.length > page limit` they both still return a `false` but there are definitely more items in the db.

Any pointers on how to go about this?