# MongoDB get more and more records

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

How can I get let's say the oldest 5 records from MongoDB using **mongoose** and after let's say the next 5 records and so on.
What I have by now is this

```
Model.find().sort({time: -1}).limit(5).exec( ...);
```

But I want after some time to get next 5, how can I do this?

Comment: Please don't insert excessive dots into your post. It will only earn you downvotes for bad look.

Comment: Don't know specifically about mongoose & nodejs, but if you want to process 5 records at a time, I would look at mongo cursor. Instead of limiting search by `limit(5)`, I would fetch 5 records from the cursor, process them, fetch the next 5 and so on. You can also, use `skip` keyword, which tells Mongo to skip certain number of records. But this requires running the query every time, which is inefficient.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5539955/how-to-paginate-with-mongoose-in-node-js

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on request number update page. eg. first request send page=0, for next page=1 and so on.

```
var limit = 5;
var page = 0; // 1,2,3,4

return Model.find()
        .sort({time: -1})
        .limit(limit)
        .skip(limit * page)
        .exec();
```

Comment: Thanks, starting with page 0 so it won't skip any at the first time works perfect!