# How to implement pagination for mongodb in node.js using official mongodb client?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, pagination

I want to implement pagination for [mongodb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MongoDB) in [node.js](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Node.js) enviroment using [offical mongodb package](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.1/quick-start/quick-start/). I tried to find out on internet but all are [mongoose](https://mongoosejs.com/) based links. I dont want to use mongoose.

How can I implement pagination using official client api given at
 http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.1/api/

Answer (score 10):

**Offset-based** approach has a big flaw: if the results list has changed between calls to the API, the indices would shift and cause an item to be either returned twice or skipped and never returned

This problem is demonstrated at
https://www.sitepoint.com/paginating-real-time-data-cursor-based-pagination/

**Time-based** pagination approach would be little better because results are no longer skipped. If you query the first page, and then a new item is deleted, it won’t shift the results in your second page and all is fine. However, this approach has a major flaw: what if there is more than one item that was created at the same time?

Best would be to use **Cursor based pagination**
Which can be implemented using any field in collection which is **Unique, Orderable and Immutable**.

`_id` satisfy all **Unique, Orderable and Immutable** conditions. Based on this field we can sort and return page result with `_id` of last document as the cusror for subsequent request.

`curl https://api.mixmax.com/items?limit=2`

```
const items = db.items.find({}).sort({
   _id: -1
}).limit(2);

const next = items[items.length - 1]._id
res.json({ items, next })
```

when the user wants to get the second page, they pass the cursor (as next) on the URL:
`curl https://api.mixmax.com/items?limit=2&next=590e9abd4abbf1165862d342`

```
const items = db.items.find({
  _id: { $lt: req.query.next }
}).sort({
   _id: -1
}).limit(2);

const next = items[items.length - 1]._id
res.json({ items, next })
```

If we want to return results in a different order, such as the date the item then we will add `sort=launchDate` to the querystring.
`curl https://api.mixmax.com/items?limit=2&sort=launchDate`

```
const items = db.items.find({}).sort({
   launchDate: -1
}).limit(2);

const next = items[items.length - 1].launchDate;
res.json({ items, next })
```

For subsequent page request
`curl https://api.mixmax.com/items?limit=2&sort=launchDate&next=2017-09-11T00%3A44%3A54.036Z`

```
const items = db.items.find({
  launchDate: { $lt: req.query.next }
}).sort({
   _id: -1
}).limit(2);

const next = items[items.length - 1].launchDate;
res.json({ items, next });
```

If we launched a bunch of items on the same day and time? Now our `launchDate` field is no longer unique and doesn’t satisfy **Unique, Orderable and Immutable**. condition. We can’t use it as a cursor field. But we could use two fields to generate the cursor.Since we know that the `_id` field in MongoDB always satisfies the above three condition, we know that if we use it alongside our `launchDate` field, the combination of the two fields would satisfy the requirements and could be together used as a cursor field.
`curl https://api.mixmax.com/items?limit=2&sort=launchDate`

```
const items = db.items.find({}).sort({
   launchDate: -1,
  _id: -1 // secondary sort in case there are duplicate launchDate values
}).limit(2);

const lastItem = items[items.length - 1];
// The cursor is a concatenation of the two cursor fields, since both are needed to satisfy the requirements of being a cursor field
const next = `${lastItem.launchDate}_${lastItem._id}`;
res.json({ items, next });
```

For subsequent page request
`curl https://api.mixmax.com/items?limit=2&sort=launchDate&next=2017-09-11T00%3A44%3A54.036Z_590e9abd4abbf1165862d342`

```
const [nextLaunchDate, nextId] = req.query.next.split(‘_’);
const items = db.items.find({
  $or: [{
    launchDate: { $lt: nextLaunchDate }
  }, {
    // If the launchDate is an exact match, we need a tiebreaker, so we use the _id field from the cursor.
    launchDate: nextLaunchDate,
  _id: { $lt: nextId }
  }]
}).sort({
   _id: -1
}).limit(2);

const lastItem = items[items.length - 1];
// The cursor is a concatenation of the two cursor fields, since both are needed to satisfy the requirements of being a cursor field
const next = `${lastItem.launchDate}_${lastItem._id}`;
res.json({ items, next });
```

Refefence: https://engineering.mixmax.com/blog/api-paging-built-the-right-way/

Comment: This is also called keyset pagination, read more about it here: https://use-the-index-luke.com/no-offset
It is generally more performant and consistent, though it should be said, it has a few limitations that the offset pagination approach doesn't, an important one being, you can't navigate to an arbitrary page.

Answer (score 5):

Using the recommended pagination approach with limit() and skip() ([see here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.skip/#pagination-example)):

```
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
MongoClient.connect('http:localhost:27017').then((client) => {
    const db = client.db(mongo.db);
    db.collection('my-collection').find({}, {limit:10, skip:0}).then((documents) => {
        //First 10 documents
        console.log(documents);
    });


    db.collection('my-collection').find({}, {limit:10, skip:10}).then((documents) => {
        //Documents 11 to 20
        console.log(documents);
    });
});
```

Here's a pagination function:

```
function studentsPerPage (pageNumber, nPerPage) {
    return db.collection('students').find({}, 
        {
            limit: nPerPage, 
            skip: pageNumber > 0 ? ( ( pageNumber - 1 ) * nPerPage ) : 0
        });
}
```

Comment: It's kind of crazy that that's the recommended approach in mongo's docs! In almost any database, skip can be a bit dangerous with a large offset because it'll need to scan through all of the docs up to the ones that you're looking for (the docs, to their credit, do mention this). I think a better pattern might be ordering by the _id field, and passing the _id that you want to get the documents before -- `{_id: {$lte: previousId}}`.

Comment: The `skip` approach is simple & clear though, and if most people aren't going to be paging through lots of documents, it's probably not worth worrying about.

Answer (score 0):

I am sending an API that is on MongoDb and Nodejs.

```
module.exports.fetchLoans = function(req, res, next) {
    var perPage = 5;
    var page = req.body.page || 1;
    loans
      .find({ userId: req.user._id})
      .select("-emi")
      .skip(perPage * page - perPage)
      .limit(perPage)
      .sort({ timestamp: -1 })
      .exec(function(err, loan) {
        if (loan != null) {
          loans
            .find({ userId: req.user._id})
            .count()
            .exec(function(err, count) {
              if (count != null) {
                res.json({
                  success: true,
                  loans: loan,
                  currentpage: page,
                  totalpages: Math.ceil(count / perPage)
                });
              } else {
                console.log("Milestone Error: ", err);
                res.json({ success: false, error: "Internal Server Error. Please try again." });
              }
            });
        } else {
          console.log("Milestone Error: ", err);
          res.json({ success: false, error: "Internal Server Error. Please try again." });
        }
      });
  };
```

In this code, you will have to provide page number on every hit.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `skip` and `limit` options to implement pagination

```
module.exports = (data)=>{

  let page = parseInt(data.page);
  let limit = parseInt(data.limit);
  let skip = 0

  if(page>1){
   skip = (page * limit);
   }


let mongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
    mongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017').then((client) => {
        let db = client.db('your-db');
        db.collection('your-collection').find({}, {limit:limit, skip:skip}).then((documents) => {
            console.log(documents);
        });

    });
};
```