# How to implement twitter and facebook api like cursor based pagination in mongodb in nodejs using official mongodb client?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, pagination, real-time

I am trying to implement [pagination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pagination) which should not show duplicate data in different pages on data insertion or deletion.

Basic [offset-based](https://developer.github.com/v3/#pagination) approach using [skip](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.skip/) and [limit](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.limit/) to paginate data is given on this
[How to implement pagination for mongodb in node.js using official mongodb client?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58219750/how-to-implement-pagination-for-mongodb-in-node-js-using-official-mongodb-client)

**Offset-based** approach has a big flaw: if the results list has changed between calls to the API, the indices would shift and cause an item to be either returned twice or skipped and never returned

This problem is demonstrated at
https://www.sitepoint.com/paginating-real-time-data-cursor-based-pagination/

**Time-based** pagination approach would be little better because results are no longer skipped. If you query the first page, and then a new item is deleted, it won’t shift the results in your second page and all is fine. However, this approach has a major flaw: what if there is more than one item that was created at the same time?

Offset-based and time-based approaches are not so perfect. So I need 
the way twitter and facebook api work, which uses cursor based approach, using nodejs and [official mongodb client](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.1/api/)?

Comment: Use ObjectId for pagination. It's unique and time-based.

Answer (score 4):

Cursor based pagination can be implemented using any field in collection which is **Unique, Orderable and Immutable**.

`_id` satisfy all **Unique, Orderable and Immutable** conditions. Based on this field we can sort and return page result with `_id` of last document as the cusror for subsequent request.

`curl https://api.mixmax.com/items?limit=2`

```
const items = db.items.find({}).sort({
   _id: -1
}).limit(2);

const next = items[items.length - 1]._id
res.json({ items, next })
```

when the user wants to get the second page, they pass the cursor (as next) on the URL:
`curl https://api.mixmax.com/items?limit=2&next=590e9abd4abbf1165862d342`

```
const items = db.items.find({
  _id: { $lt: req.query.next }
}).sort({
   _id: -1
}).limit(2);

const next = items[items.length - 1]._id
res.json({ items, next })
```

If we want to return results in a different order, such as the date the item then we will add `sort=launchDate` to the querystring.
`curl https://api.mixmax.com/items?limit=2&sort=launchDate`

```
const items = db.items.find({}).sort({
   launchDate: -1
}).limit(2);

const next = items[items.length - 1].launchDate;
res.json({ items, next })
```

For subsequent page request
`curl https://api.mixmax.com/items?limit=2&sort=launchDate&next=2017-09-11T00%3A44%3A54.036Z`

```
const items = db.items.find({
  launchDate: { $lt: req.query.next }
}).sort({
   _id: -1
}).limit(2);

const next = items[items.length - 1].launchDate;
res.json({ items, next });
```

If we launched a bunch of items on the same day and time? Now our `launchDate` field is no longer unique and doesn’t satisfy **Unique, Orderable and Immutable**. condition. We can’t use it as a cursor field. But we could use two fields to generate the cursor.Since we know that the `_id` field in MongoDB always satisfies the above three condition, we know that if we use it alongside our `launchDate` field, the combination of the two fields would satisfy the requirements and could be together used as a cursor field.
`curl https://api.mixmax.com/items?limit=2&sort=launchDate`

```
const items = db.items.find({}).sort({
   launchDate: -1,
  _id: -1 // secondary sort in case there are duplicate launchDate values
}).limit(2);

const lastItem = items[items.length - 1];
// The cursor is a concatenation of the two cursor fields, since both are needed to satisfy the requirements of being a cursor field
const next = `${lastItem.launchDate}_${lastItem._id}`;
res.json({ items, next });
```

For subsequent page request
`curl https://api.mixmax.com/items?limit=2&sort=launchDate&next=2017-09-11T00%3A44%3A54.036Z_590e9abd4abbf1165862d342`

```
const [nextLaunchDate, nextId] = req.query.next.split(‘_’);
const items = db.items.find({
  $or: [{
    launchDate: { $lt: nextLaunchDate }
  }, {
    // If the launchDate is an exact match, we need a tiebreaker, so we use the _id field from the cursor.
    launchDate: nextLaunchDate,
  _id: { $lt: nextId }
  }]
}).sort({
   _id: -1
}).limit(2);

const lastItem = items[items.length - 1];
// The cursor is a concatenation of the two cursor fields, since both are needed to satisfy the requirements of being a cursor field
const next = `${lastItem.launchDate}_${lastItem._id}`;
res.json({ items, next });
```

Refefence: https://engineering.mixmax.com/blog/api-paging-built-the-right-way/

Comment: Hello.. I'm having some issues recreating this

Comment: @Mhd: What is problem? How can I help?

Comment: Hi! Alok I am using mongo and auto generated ID but while querying in db with cursor it is giving empty results. I use Id and updatedAt. Let me share code in next comment.