# Pagination not returning correct record count

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have an API and I have implemented pagination in that. I am required to give response in this format

```
    "status": "Success",
    "message": "data found",
    "totalPages": 2,
    "currentPage": "1",
    "data": [
        {
       .....
```

So I have to display the total pages and the current page. 10 records per page. There are two tables one is users, where I am maintaining the user's activity history and the second, is chat. I have to get all the distinct chat IDs of the user and then find the latest record against that chat id. In order to achieve this, I am doing the following

```
  var query = {}
  var count = 0
  var page = 1
  var pageSize = 10

  if (req.query.page) {
    console.log("page : ", page);
      page = req.query.page
      query.skip = pageSize * (page - 1)
  }

  query.limit = pageSize

User.distinct("chatId", {userEmail:  req.params.senderEmail }, async function(err, chat){
      if(chat){
         for(var i = 0; i < chat.length;i++){
          var chats = await Chat.find({ chatId: chat[i] },{}, query).sort('-_id').limit(1).exec();
          if(chats){
              count++;
              if(typeof(chats)  === 'object'){ 
                  if(JSON.stringify(chats) !== '{}' || JSON.stringify(chats) !== '[]'){
                    chatList.push(chats);
                  }
              }
          }
        }
        console.log("count is : ", count);
        count = count/10;
        if(count<1){
          count = 1;
        }
        count = Math.round(count) 
        console.log("count after calculation : ", count);

        res.json({
            status: "Success",
            message: "data found",
            totalPages: count,
            currentPage: page,
            data: chatList
        }); 
      }
  });
```

Following are the consoles

```
page:  1
count is:  20
count after calculation:  2
```

Now the problem is that instead of getting 10 records on a single page I am getting all the records (20) on page 1. Can you please highlight where I am wrong?

Comment: Why this code should return 10 records in each page? where do you limit number of records?

Comment: @Saeed.Ataee  because in chat.find query, i'm using "{}, query"

Comment: And that means retrieve only 10 records?

Comment: yes. But it's returning 20

Comment: I cant find empty `{}` in its documents to limit data. But I find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5539955/how-to-paginate-with-mongoose-in-node-js) which uses limit!

Comment: @Aq. You are not factoring `skip` and `limit` values that you've calculated into the query. Likely the query should've been `await Chat.find({ chatId: chatId).skip(query.skip).limit(query.limit).sort('-_id').exec();`

Comment: @ambianBeing I have tried this but then I am getting the latest record against a chat id twice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the issue by storing the  Chat.find query result in an array, So the chat.find in question is changed to the following.

```
Chat.find({ chatId: chat[i] }).sort('-_id').limit(1).exec();
```

then I implemented pagination on array.

```
 if(query.skip >= 0){
   pageLimit = (query.limit) * (page)
   }
```

```
 res.json({
            status: "success",
            message: "data found",
            totalPages: count,
            currentPage: page,
            data: chatList.slice(query.skip, pageLimit)
        });
```