# Mongoose and Express JS, find documents in a range

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have a Mongo DB database with 80 or so documents. I want to only display documents from the 12th document to the 24th, or the 3rd to the 50th, etc.

What I mean by this, is since I have 80 documents, I only want to display a certain range of documents. For example, the number 12th document in the database all the way to the 24th.

How would I do this efficiently?

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to paginate with Mongoose in Node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5539955/how-to-paginate-with-mongoose-in-node-js)
Especially this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59848661/3761628

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use [`skip`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-skip) and [`limit`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#aggregate_Aggregate-limit)

```js
const perPage = 12;

let page = 0;
// Select the 1st - 12th document
await this.SomeModel
    .find(query)
    .skip(page*perPage)
    .limit(perPage);

page = 1;
// Select the 13th - 24th document
await this.SomeModel
    .find(query)
    .skip(page*perPage)
    .limit(perPage);
```