# Pagination in NodeJS API

Tags: node.js, mongodb

How do I do pagination in NodeJS API. I have the code here that has the Post.Find().populate stuffs and I am not sure at which point of the code I can do pagination using limit and offset. And by the way, if I want to do an infinite scroll, should I use limit/offset or limit/skip? Any help greatly appreciated and many thanks in advance.

```
router.get('/allpost',JWTAuthenticatToken, async (req, res) => {  
    try{
        const post = await Post.find().populate("postedby","_id displayname profileimage").populate("reviewers.postedby","_id displayname")
        res.json(post)
    }catch(error){
        res.json({message:error})
    }
})
```

Comment: I think I can go by this link for the answer. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5539955/how-to-paginate-with-mongoose-in-node-js/14822142

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can share with you how my implementation works by using ExpressJS and MySQL database. The ideas behind are:

1. Determine the `numberOfRows` of the data that you wish to display form the database.
2. Set a `pageSize` to show the number of items to be displayed in single page.
3. Always return the `page` number for the current view using `req.query`, else by default, it will be page 1.
4. By using the returned `page`, we can calculate the number of rows of data to be `skip`.
5. Lastly, setup the `limit(offset, length)` in your query.

The coding part will be:

```
var connection;
var pageSize = 20;
var numberOfRows, numberOfPages;
var numberPerPage = parseInt(pageSize,10) || 1;
var page = parseInt(pageInfo.page, 10) || 1;
var skip = (page - 1) * numberPerPage;
var limit = `${skip} , ${numberPerPage}`;

return connectionPool.getConnection()
.then((connect) => {
  connection = connect;
  return connection.query(`SELECT COUNT(*) AS total ....`); //To get total rows
})
.then(([rows, field]) => {
  numberOfRows = rows[0].total;
  numberOfPages = Math.ceil(numberOfRows / numberPerPage);
  return connection.query(`SELECT .... LIMIT ${limit}`); //Get specific data with LIMIT
})
.then(([rows, field]) => {
  result = {
    rows: rows,
    pagination: {
    current: page,
    numberPerPage: numberPerPage,
    has_previous: page > 1,
    previous: page - 1,
    has_next: page < numberOfPages,
    next: page + 1,
    last_page: Math.ceil(numberOfRows / pageSize)
    }
  }
  return result;
})
.catch((err) => {
  throw new Error(err.message);
})
.finally(() => {
  connection.release();
})
```

It's a workable code, all you need is just properly organize your returned `result` correctly in your pagination at the frontend. Although it is done by using MySQL, but I hope you get the concept behind.

Comment: thanks and greatly appreciated it

Answer (score 2):

For pagination you need values of two things
*1.current_page_no*
*2.item_per_page*

then you can code like that,

```
router.get('/allpost',JWTAuthenticatToken, async (req, res) => {  
    try{
        const post = await Post.find().populate("postedby","_id displayname profileimage").populate("reviewers.postedby","_id displayname").skip((item_per_page * current_page_no)-item_per_page)).limit(item_per_page)

        res.json(post)
    }catch(error){
        res.json({message:error})
    }
})
```

Comment: Thanks. Another method of achieving it

Answer (score 1):

For pagination you will always need to send the current page. You can either send it as an query string, param or just POST variable.

```
router.get('/allpost',JWTAuthenticatToken, async (req, res) => {  
    try{
        let page = req.body.page ?? 1;
        let limit = 10;
        const post = await Post.find().populate("postedby","_id displayname profileimage").populate("reviewers.postedby","_id displayname").skip((page * limit) - limit).limit(limit)
        res.json(post)
    }catch(error){
        res.json({message:error})
    }
})
```

I send it here with an POST.

What you do here you set an limit how much you maximum wanna display. Then you need some basic calculations.
On the first page 1 you wanna skip 0, on page 2 you wanna skip 10 on page 3 you wanna skip 20 and so on...

10 * 1 = skips 10. That means on page 1 you will skip 10. But you want to skip 0. For this you need to subtract by 10.

Comment: Thanks. I use post instead of get as Axios does not support req.body.

Comment: @Nat well that sentence actually does not make sense because POST variables are in the request body `req.body`. In this exmaple i used POST and not GET

Comment: hahaha. Yes indeed, I reread it and I find it strange also. Thanks